# Percentage Available connection alert for AWS Aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am looking forward to creating a alert/notification which is triggered when the number of available connections to an Aurora Instance go below 20%.

By this I mean an alert which will be triggered when the total number of used connections to the instance go above 80%. I am not able to find any such alarm in CW. Can someone recommend how to create such an alert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Aurora provisioned, in which case your `max_connections` parameter would be constant, unless you explicitly set a different value. There is a CloudWatch metric for the number of DB connections https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Monitoring.Metrics.html#Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Monitoring.Metrics.instances, and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Managing.html) are the default connection limits for different Aurora Postgres instance types. You can use this to compute the percentage of used connections.

If you anticipate changing the value of `max_connections` over time, you would need to monitor the value yourself and upload it to CloudWatch.